# Irreducible topological spaces covered by infinitely-many closed sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

An irreducible topological space cannot be the union of two proper closed subsets, by definition.

Is it possible thai It can be the the union of infinitely-many proper closed subsets?

How about the Noetheian case?

Comment: Sure. The affine line with the Zariski topology over, say, $\mathbb{C}$ is the union of infinitely many points.

Comment: Oh, this is easy by  removing (0). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered in a comment:

> Sure. The affine line with the Zariski topology over, say, $\mathbb{C}$ is the union of infinitely many points. –  Qiaochu Yuan Jan 10 '13 at 2:23